# How to detect text from web page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, timezone

I am new to Chrome extensions and Javascript, so I need your guys' guidelines. I need to detect times from web pages. for example on this website [ACADEMY SELECTS SHOW](https://www.oscars.org/news/academy-selects-show-dates-2016-2017-2018) I want to detect `8 a.m. PT` or `5 p.m. PT` It can be different types of timezones. How can I solve it?

Comment: If you tell us what exactly you want to do maybe we can help you.
PT stands for Pacific Time.
Are there other types of times on that site?.

Comment: @Robbi Yes, There are other types of timezones, but for the first try, I just want to search PT and highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

To find a string among several tags in body you have to think yourself first a coulple of things.
Is this kind of text always in same tags (with same property i.g. class)?
You should first try to restrict the "battlefield" as much as you can.
Then you can use a generic string "indexOf()" method applied on innerText (or textContent) of each potential tag.
Note that the above properties return only text excluding any inner tag syntax.
If you have found the desired text in a tag then you will need to check if this tag has other non-text nodes in it.
**1** If so, it means you have found out the most atomic tag that include your search string.
Now all you have to do is include the found text in a new tag to which you'll apply a class and a style.
**2** If inside the above node you'll find out other tags, you'll have to reiterate the cycle for each one of these.

**EDIT:**
if you are facing **point 2** you may avoid to cycle into inner tags, but you have to replace outer tag **innerHTML** (no innerText) with a new HTML with the replacements you've done.